# .Net core microservices Event brokers using Solace

Tags: c#, .net-core, event-handling, microservices, solace

I was trying to create a .net core project which will have multiple microservices and was trying to implement even brokers using solace for communicating between microservices. I do not see much references online for implementing it using solace in .net core . please if anyone has any sample solutions shared in github or on online , please could you share the same.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .NET Core samples are the same as the .NET Samples.

You can obtain some samples from the examples directory in the API.

1. Go to https://solace.com/downloads/
2. Scroll to "Solace APIs".
3. Click on Microsoft .NET.
4. Download and extract contents.
5. Build the samples in solclient_dotnet_10.6.0\ex\SolClientSamples\vs2017 using Visual Studio.
6. Alternatively, build from the command line via:

   C:\solclient_dotnet\ex\SolClientSamples\vs2017> dotnet build -f netcoreapp2.0 cs_sdk_examples.sln

Comment: Thanks @Russel , that's helped me to start of.